# How to fetch data of the request user in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I am creating a profile page, and need to fetch the `id` of the requesting user, so I can then loop it's information.

I am using this view:

```
def profile(request):  
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
        us = User.objects.get(username=user)
        context = { 'us': us }
    return render(request, context, "frontend/profile.html")
```

And the path:

```
path('perfil/', views.profile, name="profile")
```

But when I try access the page I get the following error:

```
join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'dict'
```

Comment: when you call `profile() `  you need to pass the id as per your code, but you need to remove id from this: `def profile(request, id):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user is already available inside your template: `{{user.username}}` or anything you want.

For your code, the render does not have good parameters:

```
return render(request,"frontend/profile.html", context)
```

Comment: Yes! I just noticed I had the context before the template. Thanks anyway. I'll mark it as correct if anyone falls onto the same mistake.